# I have a weird padding issue on my drop down css menu and don't know where it is comming from or how to remove it

Tags: css, menu, nav

I have a drop down CCS menu that works fine for me except there is a weird padding on the left of the links on the drop down and I don't understand where they are coming from. I have searched here and on the web and can't find what is causing it. Maybe I'm missing it due to inexperience but I still cannot find it. I'd like the drop down list to just be positioned center or left but without the padding shown below. Please let me know what is causing this.

```
 <div>
        <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fruit</a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Aplle</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Veggie</a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Broccoli</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Tomato</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Carrot</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>                                     
        </ul>
    </div>

HERE is my css:

    #menu{
    width:100%;
    background:#318598;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:0;
}

#menu > li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    line-height:35px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px 10px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;

}
/* Dropdown Event Properties */
#menu li ul{
   position:absolute;
   top: 35px;
   min-width:150px;
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   z-index:1;
   list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li ul li ul{
    top:0;
    left:150px;               
}

#menu li ul li a:hover{
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

#menu li ul{
    display: none;

}
#menu li:hover > ul{
    display:block;

}
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/squinny/jz4hM/

Also the fiddle doesnt really show it. The hover selector hovers over the whole drop down item, in firefox it hovers over all except maybe a quarter of the drop down item on the left hand side and is very annoying. All ideas are appreciated!

css normailized on fiddle turned off:
http://jsfiddle.net/squinny/jz4hM/7/

Comment: Turn OFF the _"Normalize CSS"_ option in your jsFiddle to see your actual code working without the CSS Reset applied.

Comment: thanks i never knew that...i turned it off, very good to know!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `min-width: 150px;` so use `width` as `auto` and set paddding accordingly

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jz4hM/3/)

CSS

```
#menu li ul{
   position:absolute;
   top: 35px;
   width:auto;
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   z-index:1;
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Or you can give `padding-right: /*Whatever*/`

[**Right Padded Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jz4hM/5/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a css reset file.

jsFiddle is using that hence why you don't see the problem there.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Alternatively, if he wants to just find & solve the actual problem, he can simply set the padding on his `<ul>`'s... same result.